# Structure declaration scope

Tags: c++, scope, compiler-errors, structure, directory

I have divided my project into this source folders:

```
src/
src/THREADS
src/UKF_IMU+GPS
src/UKF_WCT
```

I have declared the structure in this file "src/UKF_IMU+GPS/main_general.h"

**main_general.h**

```
//Structure Declarations
struct FD
{
int IMU, GPS;
};

struct S_POS
{
double X=0, Y=0, Z=0;
double Latitude=0, Longitude=0, Altitude=0;
};

struct S_IMU
{
double ACCX=0, ACCY=0, ACCZ=0, GYRX=0, GYRY=0, GYRZ=0;
double ACCX_Bias=0, ACCY_Bias=0, ACCZ_Bias=1, GYRX_Bias=0, GYRY_Bias=0, GYRZ_Bias=0;
double Pitch=0, Roll=0, Yaw=0;

//Variables to Calculate AT
double AT=0;
unsigned int Time=0;
};

struct S_GPS
{
int Date=0, TimeHour=0, NumSatUsed=0;

double Yaw=0, Velocity, Vel_X=0, Vel_Y=0, Vel_Z=0;
double Std_Dev_Lat=0, Std_Dev_Lon=0, Std_Dev_Alt=0;
double HDOP=0;

//Variables to Calculate AT
double AT=0;
unsigned int Time=0;
};
```

Then, I have declared an structure global variable object in "/src/THREADS/IMUandGPS.cpp"

**IMUandGPS.cpp**

```
#include "../UKF_IMU+GPS/main_general.h"

/* Global variables */
struct S_POS POS_Snapshot;
struct S_IMU IMU_Snapshot;
struct S_GPS GPS_Snapshot;
```

I do some stuff with the structure and it works perfect.

I also use the same global object in the other file "/src/THREADS/Write_IMUAndGPS_OF.cpp"

**Write_IMUAndGPS_OF.cpp**

```
#include "../UKF_IMU+GPS/main_general.h"

/* External Global variables */
extern struct S_POS POS_Snapshot;
extern struct S_IMU IMU_Snapshot;
extern struct S_GPS GPS_Snapshot;
```

I do some stuff with the structure and it works perfect as well.

The problem comes here, I have to use the POS global structure in this file:
"/src/src/UKF_WCT/UKF_Algorithm.cpp"

**UKF_Algorithm.cpp**

```
#include "../UKF_IMU+GPS/main_general.h"

/* External Global variables */
extern struct S_POS POS_Snapshot;

PosX = POS_Snapshot.Latitude;
PosY = POS_Snapshot.Longitude;
PosZ = POS_Snapshot.Altitude;
```

Includes and everything is the same but the compiler gives me an error:

```
forward declaration of 'struct S_POS'   UKF_Algorithm.cpp   
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct S_POS'   UKF_Algorithm.cpp   
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct S_POS'   UKF_Algorithm.cpp
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct S_POS'   UKF_Algorithm.cpp
```

PosX,Y and Z are also double so is not type problem...Why could be this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved it!

The problem was that I had another main_general.h file in "src/UKF_WCT/main_general.h" so the compiler found this file instead of "/UKF_IMU+GPS/main_general.h".

I have changed the name of the file and it works perfect!